# Whether the number of taskslots should be strictly equal to the number of cpu cores in flink? Or it can be more than the number of cpu cores

Tags: apache-flink

I am using flink standalone 5 node cluster with each task manager of 4 cpu core. Is it ok to set the number of task slot higher than the number of cpu core?

Answer (score 0):

The ratio of slots to cores is a workload-specific issue.   An I/O-intensive workload might not require a full core per slot.  Run some scale tests.

Another suggestion is to look at performance-tuning videos, such as seen at Flink Forward:
https://youtu.be/Sm5nHu7Mfsk